# ORACLE SQL JOINS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the two tables:

TABLE1:

```
id  name    values
1   john    AB
2   marry   CD
3   sreya   YG
```

TABLE2:

```
pid country     values
45  india       JKABHJ
46  usa         YURRRCD
47  uk          YGHJJKLJL
```

output

```
name    values  country
john    AB      india
marry   CD      usa
sreya   YG      uk
```

I want to join these two tables on the common columns `values`, but the other table columns contain extra data. How to overcome this?

table2 column "values" contains data matching to table1 "values"

```
values
AB
CD
YG

values
JKABHJ
YURRRCD
YGHJJKLJL
```

Comment: what is result are you excepting for?

Comment: Stop screaming at me, I'm too scared to answer now :-(

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: LOUD NOISES.... you want to join to tables together which don't have the same data in them?

Comment: output  
name values country
john AB india
marry CD usa
sreya YG uk

Comment: Add the expected result tothe question instead, formatted text.

Comment: You cannot, because one of your tables should contain something similar from the other

Comment: it has some extra data with similar ones

Answer (score 3):

You can use `like` operator in query for matching `values` in `table1` and `table2`.

For this query:

```
WITH table1 as (
    select  1 as id, 'john' as name, 'AB' as value from dual union all
    select  2 as id, 'marry' as name, 'CD' as value from dual union all
    select  3 as id, 'sreya' as name, 'YG' as value from dual
),
table2 as (
    select  45 as id, 'india' as country, 'JKABHJ' as value from dual union all
    select  46 as id, 'usa' as country, 'YURRRCD' as value from dual union all
    select  47 as id, 'uk' as country, 'YGHJJKLJL' as value from dual
)
select a.name, a.value, b.country
from table1 a
     join table2 b on b.value like '%'||a.value||'%';
```

Output:

```
NAME    VALUE   COUNTRY
john    AB      india
marry   CD      usa
sreya   YG      uk
```

But I would recommend you to change a structure to make it more efficient. For example,  by adding new table `table2_values` with column `id` referenced to `table2.id` and split `values`:

```
WITH table1 as (
    select  1 as id, 'john' as name, 'AB' as value from dual union all
    select  2 as id, 'marry' as name, 'CD' as value from dual union all
    select  3 as id, 'sreya' as name, 'YG' as value from dual
),
table2 as (
    select  45 as id, 'india' as country from dual union all
    select  46 as id, 'usa' as country from dual union all
    select  47 as id, 'uk' as country from dual
),
table2_values as (
    select  45 as id, 'JK' as value from dual union all
    select  45 as id, 'AB' as value from dual union all
    select  45 as id, 'HJ' as value from dual union all
    select  46 as id, 'YU' as value from dual union all
    select  46 as id, 'RRR' as value from dual union all
    select  46 as id, 'CD' as value from dual union all
    select  47 as id, 'YG' as value from dual union all
    select  47 as id, 'HJ' as value from dual
)
select a.name, a.value, c.country
from table1 a
     join table2_values b on b.value = a.value
     join table2 c on c.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like operator while joining the two tables.
As below

`SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.values like CONCAT('%',TABLE2.values,'%')`

Comment: The `CONCAT()` function only accepts two parameters in Oracle, and is rarely (if ever) used. It's much easier to use the `||` concatenation operator, as that can be used to join multiple string pieces together. As it stands, your sql will fail due to the presence of 3 parameters in the concat function.

Comment: yes, if you are using oracle then | | operator is the correct solution @Boneist